# WinbioOpensession returns E_ACCESSDENIED?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, biometrics, credential-providers

I am programming in VS2010 and Windows 7.

I am calling the `WinBioOpenSession` function from `winbio.h`

This is my code:

```
WINBIO_SESSION_HANDLE sessionHandle = NULL;

hr = WinBioOpenSession( 
            WINBIO_TYPE_FINGERPRINT,    
            WINBIO_POOL_SYSTEM,         
            WINBIO_FLAG_RAW,            
            NULL,                      
            0,                          
            WINBIO_DB_DEFAULT,          
            &sessionHandle             
            );
```

hr returns `E_ACCESSDENIED` return code?

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't check the biometric logon option. Go to the Biometric option of the Control Panel and enable the biometric logon option.

Answer (score 2):

Run the Visual Studio as an Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement fingerprint methods in windows service running under LocalSystem account, you need to call WinBioAcquireFocus after WinBioOpenSession to focus current session.